# Why do we not take the lulav at night?

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, evening-night

We do not take the lulav at night (e.g., https://www.ou.org/holidays/the_lulav_and_etrog/ ).  Why is that?

Comment: You want the derivation of the law or the spiritual significance behind it? Based on your tags, I'd say the former.

Comment: @robev I'm interested in both. Thx for asking.

Answer (score 2):

It is derived from the pasuk that discusses taking the minim, see
https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Sukkah/43a.9#e0n6

Comment: see too Megillah 20b